# Alternative xamarin.forms controls that aren't Telerik UI?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I've had a lot of problems trying to integrate the Telerik UI controls for my Android xamarin.forms project, and the response times on their forums are very slow. With that in mind, I'm looking for other free or paid alternatives. The main thing I need at this point is a very simple to use ListView that handles grouping. I'm aware of syncfusion, but are there any others I should be looking at?

Comment: I think these are the most prominent: https://blog.xamarin.com/enterprise-component-vendors-join-xamarin-forms-ecosystem/ and of course a lot of community built ones.

Comment: most of the major .NET component vendors offer XF libraries